# How does one properly test a javascript widget?

Tags: javascript, testing

So, I've written a little javascript widget. All a user has to do is paste a script tag into the page, and right below it I insert a div with all of the content the user has requested.

Many sites do similar things, such as Twitter, Delicious and even StackOverflow.

What I'm curious about is how to test this widget to make sure that it will work properly on everyone's webpage. I'm not using an iframe, so I really want to make sure that this code will work when inserted most places. I know it looks the same in all browsers.

Suggestions? Or should I just build one hundred web pages and insert my script tag and see if it works? I would hope there is an easier way than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have confirmed that your javascript works cross-browser in a controlled environment, here are some things that might cause problems when used on an actual website:

#### CSS

- You're using a CSS class that is already being used (for a different purpose) by the target website
- You're using positioning that might interfere with the site's CSS
- The elements you are using are being styled by the website's CSS (you might want to use some sort of ["reset"](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) CSS that applies only to your widget)

#### HTML

- You're creating elements with the same `id` attribute as an element that already exists on the website
- You're specifying a `name` attribute that is already being used (while `name` can be used for multiple elements, you may not be expecting that)

#### Javascript

- What is the expected behaviour without Javascript enabled? If your script creates everything, is it acceptable for nothing to be present without JS?

Comment: Cool, I've thankfully thought of most of those. I'm more curious if there is really any way to test that I'm not breaking any of those things on a wide variety of use cases. It sounds like I may just have to do what I originally feared.

Comment: I don't know of any absolute way to test that your widget will work with 100% of websites, because you have no way to guarantee at all what the website will be like. The best you can do is try it out with websites/code that you think could break it and update your widget to work with those.

Answer (score 1):

At very basic you should make sure your widget works for following test-cases. I am sure then it will work on all web-pages -

- **http/https**: There should not be any warning for HTTPS pages for unencrypted content.
- **<script> / <no-script>**: What if JavaScript is disabled? Is your widget still visible?
- What happens when **third-party cookies** are disabled? Does your widget still work?
- Layout-box restrictions: When parent div element's size is less than your widget. Does your widget overflow the given size and destroys owners page?

Answer (score 0):

By keeping all your Javascripts under a namespace (global object) with a *very* unique name, you should be pretty much OK. Also, you can simply use an anonymous function if you just want to print out something.

Similar question: [How to avoid name clashes in JavaScript widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628306/how-to-avoid-name-clashes-in-javascript-widgets)

Comment: I'm more worried about CSS and the HTML I inject not working, instead of namespace clashes, but thanks for the link.